# MVP, конкретно презентер и диалоги

Tags: android, android-dialog, mvp

Имеется фрагмент `А`, у которого есть собственный презентер.

На этом фрагменте `А` запускается кастомный диалог `Б` в котором есть `EditText` и кнопка.

Когда мы жмем на кнопку в `EditText` вставляется некоторый текст, который нужно вернуть обратно на фрагмент `А`.

**Вопрос:** какое количество презентеров здесь необходимо?

2: один для диалога, чтобы ходить за текстом и сеттить его в `EditText` и второй для фрагмента чтобы запускать этот диалог и производить другие операции на главной View. Или 1 чтобы делать все это вместе и сразу?
Как здесь вернее поступить?

Answer (score 1):

Точный ответ на Ваш вопрос можете дать только Вы.

Это архитектурно зависимо. Т.е. как Вы сделаете так и будет.

Лучше использовать один презентер или два - это знаете только вы.

Я бы использовал один. Но опять же - я не в курсе всего, что вы хотите реализовать.

П.с. почитайте/погуглите о best practices и подобном.

Comment: Да, я понимаю что все зависит от того, как я решу сам, но сможете ли вы аргументировать почему 1 презентер здесь лучше, чем 2 по вашему мнению? 
Читал-гуглил, но что-то никак не могу сформировать свое мнение

Comment: @whalemare, ничего личного, честно, но: ответ на Ваш вопрос "потому что мне так нравится", т.к. я не вижу реальной задачи. если Ваша задача просто текст из едиттекста в активити передавать - да зачем вам вообще презнтеры и все остальное ? Совет - почитайте о целях MVP. Ответьте себе на вопросы: "Зачем применять MVP? Что мне даст, если я буду использовать паттерн MVP? Нужен ли он здесь ?"

Comment: нет, задача куда более сложная, просто упростил ее в данном контексте, я понял Вас.

Comment: @whalemare тогда Вам нужно понять, что в вашей задаче решить использование/применение паттерна MVP. Чтобы это понять нужно прочитать про цели и необходимость применение этого паттерна. (пару слов навскидку: упрощение тестирования, разделения ответственности)

Comment: @whalemare посмотрите вот [этот](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/#0) туториал от гугл